# Excel 2016 - Group Tables

Tags: excel, vba, dax, powerquery

This should be straight forward, but for the life of me I can't figure it out...

[image]

I'm trying to combine the Date Table with the Var Table to form the Table on the Right.

Any method will be fine (Pivot, VBA, m Language, dax)

Comment: Have you attempted to write anything yourself? If so, please add the code to your post, so that we can improve upon it.

Comment: Please learn [ask], then edit your question and provide the missing details.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand the question correctly and looking at the example result - you want to join every row from the Date table with all the rows in the Var table, if that's the case then that's a Cartesian product of both tables and can be done with pivot tables data model:

1. Create PivotTable from `Date` table - important to check `Add this data to the Data Model`
2. On the PivotTable when the the right side menu opens `PivotTable Fields` click on `All` at top right
3. Check the Table1 `Date` and verify it is in the `Rows` section, repeat same steps for Table2 `Var`.
4. Make sure `Date` is above `Var` in the rows section.
5. Under PivotTable Tools click on `Design` --> `Report Layout` --> `Show in Tabular Form`
6. Under PivotTable Tools click on `Design` --> `Report Layout` --> `Repeat All Item Labels`

These steps will produce a table with similar results to what's shown in the question output.

Answer (score 0):

Pulled both tables into VBA as arrays

```
dateArr = worksheet.Range("dateTable")
varArray = worksheet.Range("varTable")
```

Main Loop

```
dim ct as Integer
ct = 1
For i = 1 To UBound(dateArr)
    For j = 1 To UBound(varArr)
        final(1, ct) = dateArr(i, 1)
        final(2, ct) = varArr(j, 1)
        ct = ct + 1
    Next j
Next i
```

And to answer the previous question.. I tried a lot of stuff, but this was the most effective for me.  It's dynamic, can be added to and changed, and the struggle was in the ct variable.. once that was figured out, it was all downhill..
Thanks for the help if you indeed tried!

Comment: Note that vba `integer` data type can have a maximum value of `2^15-1`. So if you generate more lines than that, you will generate an overflow error.  Generally better to avoid `Integer` and use `Long` (and, I have read, VBA internally processes Integers as Longs anyway).

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using adodb.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, rstWs As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    
    Set Ws = Sheets(1) 'ActiveSheet ' Sheets("Special Name")
    wsName = Ws.Name
 
    Set rstWs = Sheets(2) 'Sheets.Add  Result Sheet
    
    strSQL = "Select a.[Date], b.[Var] From "
    strSQL = strSQL & "(Select Date FROM [" & wsName & "$]) as a , (Select Var FROM [" & wsName & "$]) as b   "
    strSQL = strSQL & "Where not isnull(b.Var)  "
    
    DoSQL rstWs, strSQL
End Sub
Sub DoSQL(rstWs As Worksheet, strSQL As String)
 
    Dim Rs As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim i As Integer
 
    strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"
 
 
    Set Rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Rs.Open strSQL, strConn
 
    If Not Rs.EOF Then
         With rstWs
            .Range("a1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
            For i = 0 To Rs.Fields.Count - 1
               .Cells(1, i + 1).Value = Rs.Fields(i).Name
            Next
            .Range("a" & 2).CopyFromRecordset Rs
        End With
    End If
    Rs.Close
    Set Rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with Powerquery. First step is to import both columns as tables/queries into Powerquery. I named them tblDate and tblVar. Then one just adds a custom defined colum and defines it like shown in the screenshot
[image]
Then you just expand the table. This is the complete M-Code

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblDate"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each tblVar),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Var"}, {"Var"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom"
```

The result is

[image]